# call constructor that calls private initialization of components

Tags: java, swing

I just discovered that netbeans had the built in swing tools and so im playing around with it but ran into some trouble. How would I call the initialization from a main method. Because without the main method the program wont execute, but with it I cant just call the constructor, or cannot just call the initComponents() because it is private. How would I get this working??

```
public static void main(String [] args){


}
/**
 * Creates new form password
 */
public password() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
...
```

Comment: You wouldn't, you would create a new instance of the object, which would create it.  If you added other constructors, they would need to call the default constructor (either via `this` or `super` depending on your structure)

Comment: tried using this to no avail

Comment: In future, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MadProgrammer has already mentioned, you just have to create an instance of the class, calling its constructor, something like this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Class extends JFrame
{
    private JButton btn;
    private JTextArea txtArea;

    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                new Class();// Creating an instance of Class
            }
        });
    }

    public Class()
    {
        super("Title");

        initialize();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        btn = new JButton("Click me");
        txtArea = new JTextArea();

        add(btn, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(txtArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i tried this because I figured it was something like this. I was working on the same thing earlier, different project and this time I was just using a jpane vs earlier jframe. its working fine because I restarted, tho yes this answers my question